# DJI Onboard SDK in Python

Tags: dji-sdk

I am a user of DJI M600 drone. Recently, I have been able to successfully use Onboard DJI SDK to control the flight of my drone. I am using Raspberry Pi 3 (Ubuntu Mate 16) as the Onboard computer.

Currently, the Onboard SDK packages have only C++ wrappers. But, I am interested to program further in Python programming language (by using the existing C++ libraries). Has anybody been able to successfully do it? If so, could you guide me on how to do it?

Thanks in advance.